# Which Horizon endpoint GETs current token prices on the DEX?

Tags: horizon, dex

Which Horizon endpoint should we be using to access current prices for tokens?

I've read through the [docs](https://developers.stellar.org/api/aggregations/order-books/single/) entirely and am assuming the `order_book` endpoint *contains* the current price in its response. However, is this the best way?

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The current SDEX price can be retrieved from the order_book endpoint.
You can also check the liquidity_pools/POOLID/trades endpoint to see the last price from the liquidity pool.
Finally, to get the best price you should use paths/strict-send.

Comment: can you give an example of the path finding you mention? I cannot get any path queries to return a path to use in a strict payment.

Comment: https://horizon.stellar.org/paths/strict-send?destination_assets=USDC%3AGA5ZSEJYB37JRC5AVCIA5MOP4RHTM335X2KGX3IHOJAPP5RE34K4KZVN&source_asset_type=native&source_amount=100

This will give you the best path to convert 100XLM to USDC. If the path is empty, it just means there is no intermediary market that offers a best price that XLM/USDC.